# Allocating memory outside JVM and using it inside JVM

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Is it possible to create a persistent memory object outside JVM memory that can be used inside the JVM as an object, so that it survives a JVM restart?

Particular idea is that we can allocate memory outside the JVM and then use a JNI interface to access this memory and associate, say, some Java array with it.

Did somebody try to perform such hack? Any platform dependency would suffice.

For example, this can help to perform optimization of in-memory DB loading during restart of the JVM process.

Comment: You'll certainly not be able to assign it to a real java array, like a `float[]` or so. But you *can* use externally allocated memory in java, by returning it as a direct [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) that was created via JNI with [NewDirectByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer). I'm not sure how to accomplish a survivial of a JVM restart (and can not sensibly try it out at the moment), but **if** this part can be solved, a direct `ByteBuffer` is likely the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible, even without JNI.

The idea is to have a [MappedByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) backed by a "file" on [`tmpfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) filesystem. E.g. on Linux you can use `/dev/shm` (or `/run/shm`) mountpoint for that.

The performance of such MappedByteBuffer will be the same as for other Direct ByteBuffers, but it will persist the JVM restart, i.e. you can map this "file" again in a new JVM. (I write "file" in quotes, because it looks like a regular file for application, but it is actually a shared memory region that resides in RAM). We actively use this technique for our production in-memory caches.

Comment: Linux was not mentioned in the question.... So this is platform specific - or is there something similar on Windows?

Comment: @Marco13 On windows you can use a ramdisk but I think you have to install this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use MappedByteBuffer yourself or you can use a data structure built on top of a MappedByteBuffer so it can be available on restart and even shared between JVMs.

[Chronicle-Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) has a key-value store modelled as a ConcurrentMap. e.g. `Map<String, YourType>`

[Chronicle-Queue](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue) is a journal of every event in your system e.g. a log you can consume in real-time.

These are both open source and free and save you having to work out how to store and retrieve objects from a persisted store.

Note: as these are off-heap and persisted, they can be TBs in size without impacting the GC pauses times.