# ChronicleMap and Graph DB

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054165/how-to-persist-large-java-object-between-invocations-of-jvm-run), is it possible to use ChronicleMap to capture a property graph as a memory-mapped file? Currently we are hosting our graph in AWS Neptune, but would like to query it locally, but off-heap, on each of our (Java) application servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graph database, you could use neo4j as I believe it stores data off heap.

Chronicle Map is designed for key-value pairs, where the keys and values can be efficiently serialized independently as tree structures. i.e. they can't have circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Our goal is to export and memory-map the graph locally on the client, and as such we are trying to see if any system already exists that enables this. Neo4j utilizes memory-mapping, but it's done on the server itself so it doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @Kevin if you can structure the data as key-value pairs, Chronicle Map will do what you want.

Comment: yes i've thought about that but was exploring all other possible options first - haven't yet dived into what the complexity would be to convert the graph to key-value pairs.